# How do I update the UI in the middle of this thread?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Below is a block of code that runs in a separate thread from my app's main thread. How do I get the UI to update after each button gets its thumbnail? Right now it doesn't update until the whole method finishes. The buttons are already added to a UIScrollView.

(LotsGridButton is just a UIButton with some extra properties.)

```
- (void)fetchThumbnails {
    CCServer* server = [[CCServer alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<[buttons count]; i++) {
        LotsGridButton* button = [buttons objectAtIndex:i];     
        if (button.lot.thumbnail) continue;
        // load the thumbnail image from the server
        button.lot.thumbnail = [server imageWithPath:button.lot.thumbnailURL];
        [button setImage:button.lot.thumbnail forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [server release];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In place of `setImage:forState:`, take a look at the `performSelectorOnMainThread:` method, e.g.:

```
[myButton performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setThumbnail:) withObject:[server imageWithPath:myButton.lot.thumbnailURL] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: sweet! it worked, once I made a wrapper method (since performSelector only takes one arg and setImage:forState: takes 2). is this an instance of a general pattern, like "change the widget in the main thread and it'll show its changes right away"?

Comment: On the iPhone, at least, UI updates take place on the main thread. You can't reliably update widgets from background threads. So by running a method on the main thread that performs UI updates, you're more likely to get faster UI updates.

Answer (score 3):

I've no experience with the iPhone but in Cocoa in general you're supposed to update the UI only from the main thread.

From a different thread you can execute code in the main thread by using NSObject's:

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```