# iPhone: Scroll to last item in UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, scroll, collectionview

Im creating a viewcontroller with an **UICollectionVIew** with the images from the users library.

After the assets are loaded and i reload the data from the UICollectionView, i try to scroll to the last item in the UICollectionView.

The UICollectionView is filled, but i receive an error when scrolling to the last object.

Here's my code

```
void (^assetEnumerate)(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) = ^(ALAsset* result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){
    if (result != nil){
        [_assets addObject:result];
    }
};

void (^ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock)(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
    if(group != nil){
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerate];
        [_collectionView reloadData];

        //OLD:
        //no mather what is filled in the indexPathForRow, it results in an error
        //[_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];

        //NEW: fix!
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [_collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[_collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];
        });
    }
};

void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error) = ^(NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Couldn't enumerate group");
};

[_library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock failureBlock:ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock];
```

The error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UICollectionViewData.m:485
2012-11-06 00:53:17.388 iBoob[6016:c07] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'must return a UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance from -layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: for path <NSIndexPath 0x968af20> 2 indexes [0, 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2988012 0x14e7e7e 0x2987e78 0xf7df35 0x95f3f2 0x93794e 0xa7e4 0x3fd46 0x2981e7c 0x2981a16 0x2981925 0x3fb8c 0x33eb53f 0x33fd014 0x33ed7d5 0x292eaf5 0x292df44 0x292de1b 0x20ca7e3 0x20ca668 0x42f65c 0x60cd 0x2ab5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem stems from the fact that the block passed to `enumerateGroupsWithTypes` is not executed on the UI thread. Try using `performSelectorOnMainThread` to execute your code that updates your UI as described in this question:

[How do I update the UI in the middle of this thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805410/how-do-i-update-the-ui-in-the-middle-of-this-thread)

Comment: Thanks, going to check it out tonight

Comment: I wanted to scroll the collection view to the selected item when the view appears and I had exactly the same error description, but I'm performing everything on the main thread. Any idea?